# Where can I look up the amount of omega-3 in unit weight of monkfish?

Tags: fish, fat, nutrient-composition

Where can I look up the amount of  omega-3 in unit weight of monkfish? I would like to compare that to mackerel. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A Google search offered me [this site in German](https://www.fischlexikon.eu/naehrwerte/tabellen/naehrwerte.php?fisch_id=0000000083), which gives the following values for EPA and DHA (the two Omega-3 fatty acids) :

- Monkfish: 49 mg EPA + 212 mg DHA = 261 mg per 100 g fish
- Mackerel: 588 mg EPA + 739 mg = 1327 mg per 100 g fish

In other words, more than 5 times as much for the mackerel. Since mackerel tends to be overfished (more so than monkfish, at least), you might consider omega-3 supplements if you want to be conscious of environmental aspects.

Comment: So.... OP asked for where they can look up Omega-3 in unit weight, this answer provided it. OP wants the link to compare mackerel to monkfish, this answer includes those specific details.

Why the downvote?

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering what monk fish is called in German? Does the website have an English version? Or do you find any similar website in English?

Comment: Monk fish is called "Seeteufel" (literally, sea devil) in German, as Google will tell you. You can also use Google Translate to translate the site into English, as there seems to be no English version.